# Nim how to define constructors?

Tags: oop, nim-lang

Is there a way in Nim to define constructors for an object?
For example I have

```
type Deck* = ref object
    cards* : array[52, Card]
```

can I create an empty constructor that creates automatically all the cards?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
type
  Card = int
  Deck* = ref object
    cards* : array[52, Card]

proc newDeck: Deck =
  new result
  for i, c in result.cards.mpairs:
    c = i
```

Comment: The `new` operator should now be avoided.